# Where is the "Debug in Chrome" menu option for React Native with the iOS Simulator?

Tags: debugging, react-native

I'm trying to get better debugging with React Native. In the [React Native documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/debugging.html#content) it says you can get a debugger with Chrome somehow by selecting "Debug in Chrome". Where is this "Debug in Chrome" menu item? I can't find it! I'm looking in the iOS Simulator Debug menu and there's no option that says Debug in Chrome.

> To debug the JavaScript code in Chrome, select Debug in Chrome from
>   the developer menu. This will open a new tab at
>   http://localhost:8081/debugger-ui.

Answer (score 5):

I guess you were finding in wrong place, it's not in head menu. Open your React-Native app in iOS simulator and press `⌘ + d` (or shake in real device) then you will see it.